# Mail server and website on the same domain

Tags: domain-name-system

I have mail server installed on compositepipes.ru, there are domain DNS records:

```
\* A 91.200.84.73

@ MX mx.compositepipes.ru. 10

mx A 91.200.84.73
```

What should I change to be able to open website via compositepies.ru (it is at 91.200.84.**72**)?

Answer (score 1):

Change the A record for the apex domain to the IP address of the webserver. You might want to throw in a www record as well for people who are still assuming that that's the way to contact a web server.

```
\* A 91.200.84.72

@ MX mx.compositepipes.ru. 10

mx A 91.200.84.73
www A 91.200.84.72
```